# How to make user home folder after account creation?

Tags: home-directory, users, adduser

I created a new user with `useradd name` and forgot to use `-d -m` to create their home directory.  I tried making one, copying the contents of /etc/skel, and `chown`ing everything to the new user.

Aliases don't work, such as `ll`, and I just have a `$` at the command prompt, instead of `name@server ~$`.
Also, using the scroll wheel dumps garbage on the command line :(

How do I fix this, or is it easier to delete the user and start over?

Comment: I haven't figured out what else was needed from that point, but I fixed it by deleting the user and directory and starting over with adduser instead of useradd.

Comment: I think that would result in a different userid and groupid which may or may not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 82):

You have `$` at the command prompt because you are using the `sh` shell.

The shell with `name@server` is based on the `bash` shell.

You have to change the default shell for the newly created user via : `usermod -s /bin/bash` .

<strike>Using `usermod` again to add the user home directory if it wasn't present. `usermod -d /home/username`</strike>

If the user has no home directory specified in `/etc/passwd` :

Run `mkhomedir_helper <username>` to create the home directory. `mkhomedir_helper` will create the user home directory and copy the stuff in `/etc/skel` as well.

If the user already has a home directory specified in `/etc/passwd` :

Such as via `usermod -d /some/directory` , `mkhomedir_helper` will not work. The only way is to manually create the home directory for the affected user.

Comment: My output from that last command was 'usermod: no changes' even though there's no directory in the home folder

Comment: @AlxVallejo , thanks for the comment. I did some testing and edited my answer accordingly. Hopefully it helps answer your question as well.

Comment: @iridescent Thanks for your testing. The hint about the shell is helpful. I think your description of the two cases is almost complete but unintentionally misleads a bit by describing "the _only_ way" at the end. Indeed, the home directory must be specified in /etc/passwd. This is independent of /home having a <username> directory on disk, preventing `mkhomedir_helper` from completing. A quick `rm -rf /home/<username>` should allow `mkhomedir_helper <username>` to complete the tasks manually performed by the @Zenexer script below.

Comment: `sudo mkhomedir_helper <username> ` worked for me. mkhomedir_helper fails silently without sudo.

Comment: I had to use `mkhomedir_helper my_user 0077` in order to match other home directories (700 or drwx------.)

Comment: Don't forget sudo in the both the commands provided 
#Creates home dir 
```sudo mkhomedir_helper jira1```
#Runs defined shell on logging into user 
```sudo usermod <username> --shell /bin/bash```

Answer (score 34):

If you forgot to use `-d -m`, the best and quick option is to run

```
sudo mkhomedir_helper username
```

with creates the home directory as if you would have provided the missing options.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick bash script.  Run as root with `sudo`.  It takes any number of arguments, each being a username in need of a home directory.  This makes a few assumptions: that your home directories are in `/home`, and that your skeleton directory is `/etc/skel`.  These are the defaults on Ubuntu.  You can download or `wget`/`curl` this script from [gist](https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/5820858).

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Syntax: $_ USER[ USER[ ...]]" >&2
    exit 1
fi

exit_code=0

for user in "$@"; do
    home="/home/$user"
    cp -R /etc/skel "$home" && echo $'\e[32m'"Copied skeleton to: $home"$'\e[m' || ( exit_code=$?; echo $'\e[31m'"Failed to create: $home"$'\e[m' ) >&2
    chown -R "$user:$user" "$home" && echo $'\e[32m'"Set owner on: $home"$'\e[m' || ( exit_code=$?; echo $'\e[31m'"Failed to set owner on: $home"$'\e[m' ) >&2
done

exit $exit_code
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the `xdg-user-dirs-update` command. It will create the default X windows directories: Desktop, Download, etc...

A user without the the the default directories can run `xdg-user-dirs-update --force` to create the directories. I had to do this for one of my user accounts.

I recommend reading the man page before running the `xdg-user-dirs-update`  command.  The man page for  `xdg-user-dir`  adds a few more details.

The "XDG Base Directory Specification" is part of the freedesktop.org specifications.

Answer (score 4):

To change the default value of the new user's home directory, you can give

```
sudo useradd -D --base-dir /home/new_user
```

command. See **useradd -D [options]** from

```
man useradd
```

Comment: When I did
  echo $HOME
after just using useradd, it gave me /home/new_user, so I don't think that was the problem, unless that wasn't a good indicator.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question.  I only say this because this command is for changing the default values on your system, and can cause damage if you use it expecting something else.

Comment: It seems that I wrongly understand what --base-dir option does. According to the useradd man page, --base-dir option does "The default base directory for the system if -d HOME_DIR is not specified.  BASE_DIR is concatenated with the account name to define the home directory.". So I thought that this option will move old user's home to new user's home.

Comment: This is NOT correct. In fact, this causes all future user homes to be created under `/home/new_user/new_user` instead of just `/home/new_user`. To correct this, do `sudo useradd -D --base-dir /home`

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this (Ubuntu 12.04) and I solved it by creating a temp user, copying over the user directory, chowning it, and finally deleting the temp user.

```
sudo adduser temp
sudo cp -r /home/temp /home/name
sudo chown -R name.name /home/name
sudo deluser temp
```

Comment: How do I change the $HOME for "name"?