# chown: cannot access '/home/myusername/ .cache/mozilla/':No such file or directory

Tags: 20.04, firefox, chown

I tried a command (**sudo chown $username: -R ~/.cache/mozilla/firfox/**) to run firefox because I got error when try to open the Firefox. The error is **Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible**. At the time of troubleshooting with the Firfox it seems like my home directory does not exist. If this is the situation how can I fix the Ubuntu 20.04.

I am attaching the error message herewith

[image]

Black portions are my username.

Update the question:

I used [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335961/how-can-i-retrospectively-create-a-default-home-directory-for-an-existing-user-i/546090#546090) to create a home directory. Now if I run the command **ls -l /home** I can found my username. This is as follows

**drwxr-xr-x 3 myusername myusername 4096 Nov 21 13:47 myusername**

However when I use **sudo chown $myusername: -R ~/.cache/mozilla/ ~/.mozilla/firfox** I got the error **chown: cannot access '/home/myusername/ .cache/mozilla/':No such file or directory**

I can open the home directory but that is empty. Do I need to create a directory in my username within the home directory?

What's wrong with my home directory?

In addition to that, you can see the terminal only have **$** sign, no path information there.

Comment: Can you show the output from the following command:
ls -la /home

Comment: I received the message after using the command **ls: invalid option --'/' Try 'ls --help' for more information**

Comment: @Encipher try to cut-and-paste the command ...

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Please avoid screenshots of text. Instead, copy-and-paste the text into your question, [suitably formatted](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Your output clearly shows a /home directory. Please answer @EdwardKennedy's question. We cannot help you without that information.