# Home directory not being created

Tags: command-line, bash, users, home-directory

I am trying to understand system administration on Ubuntu. So, as an example, I create a dummy user using

```
sudo useradd -d /home/linda linda
```

and `passwd` to create the password. I check that an entry has been made using `cat /etc/passwd`

```
linda:x:1004:1004::/home/linda:/bin/sh
```

However, when I `su - linda`, I get

> ```
> No directory, logging in with HOME=/
> ```

and indeed, no home directory has been created. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

`man useradd` states:

```
useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian,
administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.
```

Note the **low level utility**

To add a user, use `adduser` instead. It's a more high-level utility.

---

Moreover, looking at the `-d` option:

```
   -d, --home HOME_DIR
       The new user will be created using HOME_DIR as the value for the
       user's login directory. The default is to append the LOGIN name to
       BASE_DIR and use that as the login directory name. The directory
       HOME_DIR does not have to exist but will not be created if it is
       missing.
```

**The directory will not be created if it is missing.**

Generally, keep away from `useradd`, use `adduser` instead.

Comment: In the OP's defense, when I read "On Debian,", I thought it meant on Debian as opposed to Ubuntu distros.  I am aware that Ubuntu is built on Debian but thought that a distinction was being made.

Comment: I used `adduser` but still the created home directory only contains a file `examples.desktop` and nothing else. How can I get Ubuntu to create the default folders Desktop, Downloads and so on? (I'm logged in via ssh)

Comment: Hi, sorry late response and only guessing but I think those folders are created automatically on the first GUI login. Just thought people might still land here ;)

Comment: `adduser` will not create the directory either if someone has changed CREATE_HOME in /etc/login.defs  to "no". You can override this with the `-m` flag.

Comment: that was great thank you it solved my problem also

Comment: note for rhel users: i think this question/solution also applies. on centos7 you have to yum install `shadow-utils` to get `adduser` and then you can use `adduser`.

Answer (score 52):

you can fix this simply by creating the home dir.

```
mkdir /home/linda
chown linda:linda /home/linda
```

try logging in again and this should work.

Answer (score 28):

According with `man useradd`, `-d /home/linda` option will not create the directory `/home/linda`, if this is missing. So, you have to create it manually. To do this, run the followings commands in terminal:

```bsh
sudo -i                            #to get root privileges
mkdir /home/linda                  #to create the directory /home/linda
cp -rT /etc/skel /home/linda         #to populate /home/linda with default files and folders
chown -R linda:linda /home/linda   #to change the owner of /home/linda to user linda
```

See also: [How to make user home folder after account creation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152707/how-to-make-user-home-folder-after-account-creation)

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

Look at `/etc/defaults/useradd` if you want to change the defaults. Use:

`useradd -m -d /home/joe -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: "According with man useradd, -d /home/linda option will not create the directory /home/linda" so no, this is not a solution.

Comment: According to the useradd man page, that's what the -m flag is for:```-m, --create-home
Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. The files and directories contained in the skeleton directory (which can be defined with the -k option) will be copied to the home directory.
useradd will create the home directory unless CREATE_HOME in /etc/login.defs is set to no.```@astrojuanlu

Answer (score 12):

Use `-m` instead of `-d`, so the directory will be created for you:

`sudo useradd -m linda`

Also, if `linda` is a normal user, you might want her to use `/bin/bash` as default `shell`:

`sudo useradd -m linda -s /bin/bash`

Answer (score 5):

You can also modify `/etc/pam.d/common-session` to make it so that a user's home directory will be created on first log in.  Add the following line to that file.

```
...
session required pam_mkhomedir.so
```

This is particularly useful if your system is on a network where the users are managed externally to your machine, by LDAP for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Add the below entry in `/etc/login.defs` and save:

```
CREATE_HOME yes
```

Now, try to create user accounts. It will create the home directory.

Comment: It worked for me. I needed to have a basic script that will remotely add/manage users on different flavors of Linux. After this change my code produces same results on all servers. Thanks.

Comment: Life saver, only solution that worked for me. Was using os.system in python to call useradd btw, so it's likely related to that.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason why you did not have the home directory created is because you did not have the `CREATE_HOME yes` in `/etc/login.defs`.

You can fix this by following what @OmPS or @Radu Rădeanu had suggested.

But that many ways to overcome this problem in future by using one of the commands below:

- Result of `sudo adduser linda`

  ```
  Adding user 'linda'
  Adding new group 'linda' (1001) ...
  Adding new user 'linda' (1001) with group 'linda' ...
  Creating home directory '/home/linda' ...
  Copying files from '/etc/skel' ...
  ****Password confirmation****
  ****Name prompt****
  ```

  The defaults for adduser are chosen from `/etc/adduser.conf` if
  `--home` option is not specified.
  **Note that it also copies the `/etc/skel` contents.**
- Use adduser with `--home`

  ```
  sudo adduser --home /home/linda
  ```

**Same as previous option except that you may want this if the users
home directory is different than the username that you assigned.**

- Specify base directory to `useradd` command:

  ```
  sudo useradd -b /home
  ```
- Use login.defs: Modify `/etc/login.defs` and add the line below before doing `sudo useradd`:

  ```
  CREATE_HOME   yes
  ```

Note: if you do `man login.defs`, it currently says

**Much of the functionality that used to be provided by the shadow password suite is now handled by PAM. Thus, /etc/login.defs is no longer used by passwd(1), or less used by login(1), and su(1). Please refer to the corresponding PAM configuration files instead.**

- Use pam_mkhomedir PAM module: from `man pam_mkhomedir` page, add the line below to `/etc/pam.d/login`:

  ```
  session  required  pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel
  ```

Answer (score 2):

`useradd` command doesn't create a home directory automatically, regardless of the default settings in `/etc/login`. You have to specify the `-m` option if you want a home directory for a system account to be created.

Answer (score 1):

Use `adduser`.

```
DESCRIPTION

 adduser  and  addgroup  add users and groups to the system according to
   command    line    options    and    configuration    information    in
   /etc/adduser.conf.   They  are  friendlier  front ends to the low level
   tools like useradd, groupadd and usermod programs, by default  choosing
   Debian  policy conformant UID and GID values, creating a home directory
   with skeletal configuration, running a custom script,  and  other  fea‐
   tures.  adduser and addgroup can be run in one of five modes:
```

`useradd` you have to add all options yourself. Including permissions and some other things.`adduser` does this based on sane defaults (and also adds home dir by itself).

If you need to use adduser you probably need the -b option together with the -d option!

Answer (score 1):

If `/home/linda` is not present before you add linda as a user, you also would have to add `--create-home`.

```
sudo useradd --create-home linda
```

Answer (score -1):

My issue was that SELinux was preventing creation of home directory upon login by an unprivileged user:

```
$ ls -ldZ /home/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:root_t:s0 /home/
```

That `root_t` was preventing it from happening. I had to re-label it as:

> chcon system_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 /home/

Comment: SELinux is not used in Ubuntu. How did you even enable it?

Comment: @muru it's not *used* in Ubuntu by default, but users *can* install it from the repositories and set it up on their system themselves.  However, **SELinux is not well supported in Ubuntu**, meaning that you are likely to break things by using it.  AppArmor is the application restrictions system that is in place instead of SELinux on Ubuntu by default.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not know about Ubuntu. My solution is based off CentOS 9 (RHEL 9).