# Can't login 18.10 - "no directory logging in with home=/"

Tags: login-screen, home-directory

I might have moved my home folder by mistake, and now I'm stuck in a login loop. Every time I log in, the screen just flashes as if it logs in and then asks me to log in again. When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and logging in it says

```
no directory logging in with home=/
```

I've looked around and it seems I've messed up the location of my home folder. But how do I fix it?

Comment: So I've used locate username and now typed sudo mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/ (Ubuntu is my username). Do I need to do anything else or is that it?

Comment: Okay, so I did it. Can't logi still but something changed cause now it logs in to a blank screen for 10 secs or so before sending me back to login again.

Comment: It just seemed to run through the whole system, outputting all files and their paths (if that makes sense)? Yes I did a system shutdown and tried logging in.

Comment: There is like several thousands of lines...

Comment: How will I save and upload it when I can't login? (Sorry for alle the questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am hoping you have GRUB or some sort of bootloader which will make this repair easier, otherwise you will need to make repairs by mounting your filesystem on a separate system which works.

If you open grub and add `systemd.unit=emergency-net.target` to your command line options it will boot your system into emergency mode which should drop you into a root command prompt where you can fix any issue with your system.

If you are not worried about the old content of the directory you can just create another for your user.  You can create a directory for your user automatically by running `mkhomedir_helper username`

Comment: I have a bootloader. The system is dual booted. But could you explain in more detail what to do or send a link?

Comment: @Mikkel I assumed you could not login to your system.  If you are able to login or access the files in another way you can create the directory from your other bootable OS (assuming it is Linux).

Answer (score 0):

@Kulfy suggested this link: [Older thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/374870)
That did it. Could login and access my folders!