# Ubuntu 18.04 login loop caused after running fsck

Tags: 18.04, login

I have been a Linux (Ubuntu) user for over 5 years now, currently running Ubuntu 18.04 on my Acer laptop. I always put my laptop to sleep instead of shutting it down to resume from whatever I was doing quickly. Sometimes if I try restarting it, it boots to the advanced section saying some part of the disk is corrupt and requires I run `fsck`. I have never run into a major issue performing this operation until recently. After executing fsck on the `/dev/sda4` (my main hard drive) I couldn't log in again . It became an infinite login loop. I tried every solution I found online but none worked. I created another user through tty and could successfully log into the new account, but not my own.

What else can I try?

Comment: Hi, someone downvoted your question and the possible reason is that you reported your problem but **you didn't really ask a question** (e.g. _"How can I restore my original user account?"_) Furthermore, your problem seems to be related to the one reported at https://askubuntu.com/questions/892057/my-home-folder-home-user-is-changed-to-desktop/. Therefore, I suggest that you `[1]` edit your question so it becomes an actual question (please specify what exactly you want to know) and I also recommend that you `[2]` try the solutions reported in the previously cited answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to tty using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f3</kbd> on the Ubuntu login screen. Entered the username and password, then logged in.

I deleted the `/home/<account-name>/.config` folder which I believe harbors some files that might be executed on login and after that I was able to log in successfully.

Maybe the `fsck` operation messed up some files there. This after 2 weeks of headache and searching the web for solutions.

Comment: On GUI login, temporary work files are created for use during your GUI operation. If there is insufficient space, the login fails and you are logged out (no error message). Those work files aren't required for text logins, so you need to login & delete sufficient files (in $HOME or your user account) to create sufficient space so as the required work files can be created. I suspect all you did was create sufficient space