# How do I fix .bashrc not having colors on one machine with identical config as another?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, steam, colors

I'm spinning up a bunch of identical servers but I don't have my ops deployment set up yet. Well, I already made a mistake in initializing the first server, namely, `useradd steam` not `adduser steam`.

[first server has no colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GQ97.png)

[I tried to repair the user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152707/how-to-make-user-home-folder-after-account-creation) using `mkhomedir_helper steam`, as well as switching the user directory to /home/steam1 and back to /home/steam. I didn't make the mistake on my second server, and that one has colors on it.

[second server has no colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DCJR.png)

I've tried to copy the `.bashrc` from both the root account and the `/etc/skel`

```
rm /home/steam/.bashrc;sudo cp /root/.bashrc /home/steam/.bashrc
rm /home/steam/.bashrc rm /home/steam/.profile /home/steam/.bash_logout;sudo cp /etc/skel/.* /home/steam
```

After each of these commands, I disconnected and reconnected to my box, but I still had no colors. I also tried to set `force_color_prompt=yes`, but that did not fix the colors issue either.

Any ideas on how I can fix this user account to have colors? Any new user I create on the box and root also have colors.

Comment: Maybe the difference is that `useradd` sets the login shell to `/bin/sh` rather than `/bin/bash` so it's not reading `~/.bashrc` at all? Check the value of `SHELL` in `/etc/default/useradd`

Comment: I did `cat /etc/passwd/` and it's set to `steam:x:1000:1000:steam,,,:/home/steam:/bin/bash` in both.

Comment: The default `SHELL` is definitely `/bin/sh` and I had to change it from `sh` to `bash` after user creation.

Comment: OK - did you copy only the `.bashrc`, or the `.profile` as well? the latter will be the one that affects login shells (and in fact sources `.bashrc` by default). In fact if you want to do what `adduser` does, then copy ALL the files from `/etc/skel`

Comment: At first I only copied `.bashrc`, but I updated my question with my attempt at copying `.profile` and `.bash_logout` as well.

Comment: @steeldriver Turns out I was appending my environment variables to an empty `.bash_profile` file :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used one of my image scripts to add my custom environment variables to `.bash_profile` (as I'm used to doing on Red Hat distros), not knowing that Ubuntu uses `.profile` instead, and that by defining `.bash_profile` I was overriding `.profile`.

I moved my variables into `.profile` and deleted `.bash_profile`, and this was fixed.