# Remote Desktop -- blue screen after login

Tags: 18.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, xrdp

I've installed mate and xrdp on Ubuntu 18.04. Now I try to connect to this PC from another Ubuntu with Remmina:

[image]

I press OK, login window disappears background is same,nothing happens. My **~/.xsession** contains **mate-session**.

xrdp.log contains stuff like this:

```
[20190818-12:23:09] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20190818-12:23:12] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20190818-12:23:15] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connection problem, giving up
[20190818-12:23:15] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20190818-12:23:15] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: some problem
[20190818-12:23:15] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20190818-12:23:15] [DEBUG] Closed socket 16 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 59402)
[20190818-12:24:11] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20190818-12:24:11] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20190818-12:24:11] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20190818-12:24:11] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20190818-12:24:12] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
[20190818-12:24:12] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
[20190818-12:24:15] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20190818-12:24:19] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20190818-12:24:22] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20190818-12:24:26] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20190818-12:24:29] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20190818-12:24:33] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20190818-12:24:36] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
```

```
[20190818-12:30:30] [INFO ] calling auth_start_session from pid 6502
[20190818-12:30:30] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
[20190818-12:30:30] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
[20190818-12:30:30] [INFO ] /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log  
[20190818-12:30:40] [ERROR] X server for display 10 startup timeout
[20190818-12:30:40] [CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 6503) to exit
[20190818-12:30:40] [ERROR] X server for display 10 startup timeout
[20190818-12:30:40] [ERROR] another Xserver might already be active on display 10 - see log
[20190818-12:30:40] [DEBUG] aborting connection...
[20190818-12:30:40] [CORE ] window manager (pid 6503) did exit, cleaning up session
[20190818-12:30:40] [INFO ] calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 6502
[20190818-12:30:40] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets:
[20190818-12:30:40] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /var/run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_chansrv_socket_10
[20190818-12:30:40] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /var/run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdpapi_10
[20190818-12:30:40] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: failed to delete /var/run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdpapi_10
[20190818-12:30:40] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username someuser, display :10.0, session_pid 6502, ip ::ffff:192.115.120.210:44136 - socket: 12
```

How do I fix or diagnose this brilliant piece of software?

Comment: If you don't require the use of rdp, you could try vnc.  It works well, at least for me. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers

Comment: I tried already. Its either poor picture quality or deadly slow...

Comment: I have the same problem. I'd like to try any of the solutions posted, but the problem is I can't connect (as described), so I don't have a shell prompt. Sounds like I am being really stupid, but how do you try any of these solutions if you can't connect to the server?

Comment: well, you can connect over ssh and make changes to the system from the command prompb.

Comment: I am not sure if this is related to the problem mentioned here. But anyway I want to put it here if someone come across to this question and read this comment. DO NOT TURN ON UBUNTU ON FULL SCREEN MODE IN ALL MONITOR. It will keep kicking you out of the system and come back to blue screen login. I have observed this behavior with ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I kept one screen 4k and it worked like a charm. I spend days trying to find what is the problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found an alternative solution:

```bsh
apt-get install x2goserver
```

This will install x2go, which is opensource remote desktop server for Linux with `x2goclient` available both for Linux and Windows. Please note this software is way better then xrdp, but is also buggy. To use it, install for example mate desktop instead of linux default, default doesn't work with it yet:

```bsh
sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

When you create a connection with [this windows client](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/download:start), you will need to set MATE desktop here:

[image]

It can work with some other desktops, but for default Ubuntu -- I was unable to make it work.

It has some bugs, which I can tolerate:

- You might have issues with multiple keyboard layouts, to walk around this, you have to connect when EN layout is enabled on Windows, later you can switch to your national keyboard.
- Clipboard is buggy and suddenly stops working. You solve it by reconnect.
- Sometimes randomly it has keyboard glitches, but this doesn't happen very often, I can easily tolerate this.
- If you use high DPI fonts on Windows, you may need to set this option to avoid your fonts look too big:

[image]

- If you need it to connect automatically you will need ssh key, it can't store password. System is a bit buggy in that aspect, but I've found reliable solution: you install https://cygwin.com/, generate (**ssh-keygen**) and deploy (**ssh-copy-id myself@myserver**) key and then specify key in the connection settings (see pic above).
- Sometimes, super rarely Windows client EXEcutable might give you crazy system errors, I can't remember the error message. But this message is somehow connected with Windows binaries compatibility. Super unobvious solution is to ...reboot Windows once.

Comment: The xrdp status is so poor, that this answer should be advertised everywhere. I've lost a lot of hair chasing xrdp issues, when x2go just worked. It doesn't even show up on Google when searching related terms, what a shame.

Comment: Novice question: If I install `x2go`, should I uninstall what it is replacing `xorg`, `xrdp`, or `xorgxrdp`? I'm assuming its replacing these things.

Comment: I am not sure. For x2go you will need mate desktop. Probably its good to remove this xorg/xrdp stuff.

Answer (score 11):

You do not specify exactly which version of Ubuntu 18.04 you are running. If you have doe all the updates, you should be running Ubuntu 18.04.3.... You can check this by running the following command:

```bsh
lsb_release -sd
```

If you are running Ubuntu 18.04.3, there is a known issue with `xrdp` package provided by Canonical.  The `xrdp` package cannot install the `xorgxrdp` package because of failed dependencies. This is why you cannot connect remotely to your Ubuntu.

#### Best option - Install the new `xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04` package

Install the new xorgxrdp package by issuing the following command:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04
```

This should fix your issue .

#### Dirty Quick Fix - Downgrade the `xorgxserver` package

We assume that you have already installed xRDP package and you want to fix it

```bsh
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get -y install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

More info on http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13390.

#### Better fix - use unofficial `xrdp` packages working with Ubuntu 18.04.3

Note: To use this option, please remove the `xrdp` package you have installed

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:martinx/xrdp-hwe-18.04
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xrdp xorgxrdp
```

More info at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13455.

#### Other option - use a script to perform the installation for you

Note: To use this option, please remove the `xrdp` package you have installed.

To use Ubuntu repository xrdp packages, read instructions and download the script at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13933.

To compile from source (easy way), read instructions and download the script at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13663.

Comment: After doing this, I'm seeing crashes... Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: please provide more info about what you did ?  have you used option 1, or scripted install. For scripted install, please always check for latest version of the script..the current latest version can be found at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=16817    Hope this help

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me on 20.04 (I think it applies to 18.04 too):

In `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`

I found this fix in [this comment](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1358#issuecomment-523724558). A few more
details from that comment:

> My issue was caused by custom scripts in `/etc/profile.d` with syntax
> that `/bin/sh` doesn't like (e.g. `function function_name { some; commands; }`).

This comment was from a [known issue](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1358) on the bug.

There was [another comment there](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1358#issuecomment-549393852) mentioning another fix that did not apply to my situation:

> This post seemed to fix it for me:
> http://catch22cats.blogspot.com/2018/05/xrdp-blank-screen-with-ubuntu-1804.html
>
> ```
> unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
> unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
> . $HOME/.profile
> ```
>
> By adding the above lines just before the test and exec in
> /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh, I also added the #!/bin/bash to the top of the
> file - also doing a chmod after you've changed the file is what some
> users might be forgetting.

Comment: This worked for me too (Windows 11, Hyper-V, Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: I have been fighting this issue; this was the fix for Ubuntu 20.04.  Unbelievable.

Comment: This answer also worked for me, Windows 11, Hyper-V, Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

After trying a dozen different fixes that didn't work I found my issue was having no home directory for the user(s) attempting to RDP in.

From an unrelated post: https://askubuntu.com/a/392149/1570220

> If the user has no home directory specified in /etc/passwd :
>
> Run mkhomedir_helper  to create the home directory. mkhomedir_helper will >create the user home directory and copy the stuff in /etc/skel as well.
>
> If the user already has a home directory specified in /etc/passwd :
>
> Such as via usermod -d /some/directory , mkhomedir_helper will not work. The only >way is to manually create the home directory for the affected user.

Comment: This was the issue for me, thanks