# What command can i use to create a directory such as desktop, documents, downloads etc. For a new user's in ubuntu server

Tags: command-line

In ubuntu server when i ls a newly created user i cannot find directories such as desktop, documents, downloads etc.

Comment: I guess they will be created automatically once the new user logs in to GNOME session.

Comment: On a SERVER you should stay away from /home/$USER/ and create a dedicated partition to store user data. Preferably on a different disk: easy backup, restore and maintenance. You do not want users to mess up their home: they are 1 control-h away from deleting files they should not delete :)

Comment: In particular: https://askubuntu.com/a/713708/158442

Answer (score 2):

Directories like Desktop, Documents, Music, etc. are a desktop (not server) convention.

Those directories are automatically created on an Ubuntu Desktop system, but not on an Ubuntu Server system.

If you want those directories on a server, you can easily make them yourself. There's nothing special about them:

```
mkdir ~/Documents ~/Downloads ~/Music ~/Pictures ~/Videos
```

**Warning**: Desktop Trash won't work outside of a Desktop Environment.